# What is the difference between accumulation point and $\omega$ accumulation point?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

The title says it all. Accumulation point has a widely known definition: a point in $X$ is accumulation point if every open set containing $x$ contains infinitely many points of $X$

Sometimes I browse online and see that $\omega$-accumulation point being used.

What is the difference between these two concepts?

Comment: It seems they are the same, however there is a difference between _limit point_ and _$\omega$ accumulation point_, as the former only requires a single point in every open ball containing $x$, while the latter requires infinitely many. I think the $\omega$ is to stress the infinite requirement.

Comment: To me, the standard definition of an accumulation point $x$ of $A$ is that each neighborhood of xx contains a point in $A−{x}$. This is the same as to say that there exists a net in $A−{x}$ converging to $x$. My guess is that an $\omega$-accumulation point $x$ of $A$ is such that there exists a sequence in $A−{x}$ converging to $x$, as $\omega$ is sometimes used to denote the set of natural numbers (mostly by set theorists, from what I've seen). They are equivalent in first-countable spaces. In general, an accumulation point may not be an $\omega$-accumulation point.

Comment: @QiyuWen not a sequence, but infinitely many points. Hence the $\omega$. So every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ has $A \cap U$ infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Your "widely known definition" is not actually the definition that I am used to.  I would say an accumulation point of a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is a point $x\in X$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ that is not equal to $x$.  The term "$\omega$-accumulation point" would then refer to your definition: $x$ is an $\omega$-accumulation point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.  The two notions are equivalent if $X$ is $T_1$, so you might find sources which don't distinguish the two (say, because they are only dealing with metric spaces).

Comment: It seems the literature is not consisting with the definition of these (limit/accumulation/adherence) points, tsk tsk. Math should start over and this time do not assume axiom of choice but more importantly fix these definitions

Comment: @Vlad-GayPrideWorldWide There have been more than one definition for lots of things. You just have to state your definitions once....

Comment: An example where they differ: take $\mathbb{N}$ in the discrete topology times $\{0,1\}$ in the indiscrete topology. Then $(0,0)$ is a limit point of the space, but not an $\omega$-accumulation point.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Would you use accumulation point or $\omega$ accumulation point?

Comment: A normal accumulation point, except in the definition of countable compactness (like points of total accumulation for compact spaces). A set is closed iff it contains all its acumulation points. A space is countably compact iff every infinite set has an $\omega$-accumulation point.